# Light source causing Dark spot instead of light

Tags: lighting

Alright, I can't seem to figure this out. Using cycles, I've added a light, originally a IES point light, but I've also tried a basic spotlight and I get the same basic problem.

As you see in the images, it's casting a dark shadow instead of light. Looking as the cone ref, its not the frame of my object is interferring that I can see or understand.

This shadow only goes a way if I move the light almost half way down the length, or move it well away from this column.

I tried changing the surface colour and materials (thinking that gold was causing some issue) but it didn't appear to change it.

I've included a dropbox link (I don't think I can link actual files here) of this setup, with 3 lights, my original lamp, a Spotlight lamp in the same position as well as a lamp moved down to where it doesn't have this problem.

Can anyone "illuminate" me on this? Thanks.

[image: Shadowed Spotlight]
[image: Shadowed spotlight with cone]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4956x11pu2aa73/Pilaster%20test%20-%20IES.blend?dl=0

Comment: as @moonboots says.. or check Autosmooth in the object's Data tab > Normals panel. The front face is interpolating the normals over from the faces it's connected to, on the sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not due to the light but to the *Shade Smooth* of your object, *Shade Flat* instead and it will work correctly.

Comment: I don't really understand why, but yeah that works. Thanks

Comment: I don't know either  :/